# Read document from base 64 decoded string : R

Tags: r, base64, decode, encode, base64url

Can anyone please help me in resolving the issue for opening and reading the document from decoded string in R?

Example :

1. Upload a document from HTML page and get encoded string of document as data URL in JS.
2. Encoded string is passed to R code through REST API.
3. Got a decoded URL string for a uploaded document in R code using `base64decode`.

Now, the problem is how to read any document from base64 decoded URL string in R?    OR
How to deal with encoded URL string to read original data of any document in R?

Comment: I am trying to understand what you want. It would help if you gave an example. Anyway, to encode or decode a base64 string you use package `base64enc`, but in order do the same with a url, you better use package `jose` functions `base64url_encoding` and `base64url_decoding`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have asked a general question and have posted no associated code/data. You've likely been on SO before and seen good questions. This is not a good question. Tap the R tag below your question. Go to the "Info" tab and read and heed the advice there (including the links it provides). Otherwise I fear your question will be closed in short order.